# drawing a cube with six different colored faces in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I have drawn a cube in OpenGL, but I'd like each face of the cube to be filled with a color.

This is what I've done, I don't know why only 2 faces are filled with color.

```
void DrawCube(GLfloat centerPosX, GLfloat centerPosY, GLfloat centerPosZ, GLfloat edgeLength)
{
    GLfloat halfSideLength = edgeLength * 0.5f;

    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        // front face
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // top left
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // top right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // bottom right
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // bottom left

        // back face
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // top left
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // top right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // bottom right
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // bottom left

        // left face
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // top left
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // top right
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // bottom right
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // bottom left

        // right face
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // top left
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // top right
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // bottom right
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // bottom left

        // top face
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // top left
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // top right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // bottom right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY + halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // bottom left

        // bottom face                                                                                                                                                                           // right face
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // top left
        centerPosX - halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // top right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // bottom right
        centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength, // bottom left                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ - halfSideLength, // bottom right                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  centerPosX + halfSideLength, centerPosY - halfSideLength, centerPosZ + halfSideLength  // bottom left
    };

    GLfloat colour[] = {
        255, 0, 0,
        255, 0, 0,
        255, 0, 0,
        255, 0, 0,
        0, 255, 0,
        0, 255, 0,
        0, 255, 0,
        0, 255, 0,
        0, 0, 255,
        0, 0, 255,
        0, 0, 255,
        0, 0, 255,
        100,100,100,
        100,100,100,
        100,100,100,
        100,100,100,
        200,200,200,
        200,200,200,
        200,200,200,
        200,200,200,
        40,220,75,
        40,220,75,
        40,220,75,
        40,220,75,
    };

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colour);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}
```

The output of my program is this:
[image]

As you can see I have 1 red face, 1 green face and 4 not colored faces

Comment: Colors have to be in [0, 1] range when using GL_FLOAT colors.

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to use [0,255] range colors? What should I use instead of GL_FLOAT?

Comment: @splunk Then use one of the integral types.

Comment: `GL_BYTE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_SHORT, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, GL_INT, GL_UNSIGNED_INT` Make sure that your color array also has the type you choose.

Comment: @splunk I think, you have wrong  order of vertices. By default counter-clockwise, you're using clockwise order. And of course, you have wrong colors(you should use 0.0f-1.0f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either use `GLfloat (GL_FLOAT)` but then you have to use the range of **[0.0, 1.0]**.

Or you use `GLubyte (GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)` then you will have to use the range **[0, 255]**.

This is helpful for you: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Type

Answer (score 1):

While Armen is correct, there is something else still wrong.

You forgot to turn on depth testing. That's why you can see the red side, even though from your perspective you shouldn't be able to. That's also why you can see the back green wall "through" the front wall.

Comment: And don't forget to actually request some depth bits from the OS when you create your OpenGL context.  You may not get any unless you ask for them.